# reference to the same page in html

Tags: html, css

I want to give the reference to the same page using html.
Like example
i am Susant dey ,completed my master degree from IIT Delhi.

In this sentence suppose i have given the link to **master**  and when i will click on this master link some new sentence will add in that particular place.(Like after click in master link Master of computer application should display).

The full output should be 
I am Susant dey,completed my Master of computer applications degree from IIT Delhi.
The coding i have written

```
<html>
   <body>
   i am susant dey completed my <a href="#anchor" id="check">master </a>degree from IIT Delhi.
   </body>
 </html>
```

I have to use only html.

Comment: what have you tried so far? you need to use javascript or jquery as well to achieve what you want.

Comment: To do what you are trying to do, you will have to use more than just HTML, you will need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML5 you can use the [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) element to do something similar. For example:

```
<details>
    <summary>i am susant dey completed my master degree from IIT Delhi.</summary>
    <p>More details. More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.More details.</p>
</details>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/w2NHz/)**

The `<summary>` element would contain the short text you want the user to click on, and what comes after it would be revealed when you click on it.

Comment: http://losangeles.craigslist.org/sgv/kid/4534816835.html i want to do like this... check out this link ...click on "show contact info"

Answer (score 3):

In that case, you can't do it. To capture the `click` event you need to use JavaScript. JavaScript is required to develop dynamic web pages.

You can use JavaScript to create the function to get called once the user clicks this `master` element. Then it would either set the content to visible, or will create new DOM content. But that depends on the further requirement. Until then, you should learn something like JavaScript, HTML ain't gonna do this. HTML was not designed for this function.

You can do this like this

```
<a href="#anchor" onclick="showcontent()" id="check">master</a>
<div id="#anchordetails" style="display: none">Content here...</div>
```

Above is the HTML part, content is hidden right now, below would be the JavaScript part

```
function showcontent() {
  document.getElementById("anchordetails").style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

This above code would set the content to be visible for the user.

I am going to share some good tutorials to you, read them carefully please.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript (JavaScript)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event (Events in HTML)

http://jquery.com If you ever get stuck at length JS code, minimize it using jQuery. It is better!

Comment: http://losangeles.craigslist.org/sgv/kid/4534816835.html i want to do like this... check out this link ...click on "show contact info"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do it in CSS alone, but it is NOT the most optimal way to handle such functionality.  JavaScript is the best solution for this.  But, as a proof of concept, it can be done.

Here's the jsfiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/PX6BB/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/PX6BB/)

Here's HTML code:

```
DRD's Website: (<div class = "siteDisplay">
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "showSite" />
    <label for = "showSite">show site</label>
    <label for = "showSite">http://www.functionalcss.com/</label>
</div>).
```

CSS code:

```
.siteDisplay {
    display: inline;
}

.siteDisplay > label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.siteDisplay > input,
    .siteDisplay > input + label + label {
    display: none;
}

.siteDisplay > input:checked + label {
    display: none;
}

.siteDisplay > input:checked + label + label {
    display: inline;
}
```